# On comparing the nuclear norm with the Hilbert-Schmidt norm for symmetric tensors

Tags: norms, multilinear-algebra

I am interested in the special case of a symmetric tensor $T_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}$ of rank $k$, where each index, say $i_\kappa$, where $1 \leq \kappa \leq k$, runs from $1$ to $2$. The entries of such a symmetric tensor are assumed to be complex.

I am interested in the nuclear norm $\lVert T \rVert_*$ of $T$ as well as its Hilbert-Schmidt norm, which I will denote by $\lVert T \rVert_2$.

Any two norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent, so there are positive constants, say $C$ and $D$, depending on $k$ only, such that

$$ C \lVert T \rVert_2 \leq \lVert T \rVert_* \leq D \lVert T \rVert_2.$$

Are the best values for $C$ and $D$ known, in this case, by any chance please?

As a remark, note that in this case, there are vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in \mathbb{C}^2$ such that

$$ T = v_1 \odot \cdots \odot v_k, $$

where $\odot$ denotes the symmetric tensor product, essentially by the fundamental theorem of algebra (at least, this is one way to understand this fact). I am guessing (and I think it follows from the limiting case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) that $C$ will perhaps be attained when all the $v_i$ are proportional to a single $v \in \mathbb{C}^2$. What about the other constant, $D$? Will it be attained when the $v_i$ form some kind of highly "symmetric" distribution of $k$ points on the Riemann sphere (I am guessing $2$ antipodal points if $k = 2$, an equilateral triangle if $k = 3$, a regular tetrahedron if $k = 4$, and then distributions of points somewhat similar to the Coulomb problem; I am just trying to guess)?

In short, given $k \geq 2$, and $0 \neq T \in S^k(\mathbb{C}^2)$, what are the maximizers of

$$\rho(T) = \frac{\lVert T \rVert_*}{\lVert T \rVert_2}$$

and how does the configuration of the $k$ roots of a maximizer $T_m$ of $\rho$ look like?

Facts and/or references are very welcome!

Comment: What does $\odot$ denote? Something other than tensor product?

Comment: it is the symmetric tensor product. I will edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, but I don't think there's always such a factorization. For example, take T to be the 2 by 2 identity matrix.  Maybe I am missing something

Comment: I think that you can take $v_1 = (1, i)^T$ and $v_2 = (1, -i)^T$. Then $v_1 v_2^T + v_2 v_1^T$ is twice the identity.

Comment: The $2$ by $2$ identity matrix corresponds to the complex polynomial $z^2 + 1$, which has roots $\pm i$. Switching over to homogeneous coordinates, this gives $v_1$ and $v_2$, each up to scaling.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the case when the dimension is > 2, and I was forgetting about complexes